# Can I apply joint compound over drywall primed with PVA?

Tags: drywall, primer, mudding, taping

I hung drywall ceiling in my basement. I got impatient/lazy and decided to "finish" the project already by painting it with **Kilz PVA Drywall Primer**, even if the mudding & taping is not perfect yet.

I would say some taped joints need one more layer of mud & light sanding to be completely hidden (especially the outside corners with the **CGC Perfect 90** tape (If I used normal folded paper tape, It would've shown less).

I haven't painted it with Latex. The primer is white and flat, which I think looks OK for now.

Should I decide to "fix" it, can I mud over the PVA primer?

Comment: Being a hack taper myself I've fixed my work after priming many times. It's never been a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely mud over cured primer. (Or cured finish paint, for that matter.)

Use all purpose mud (not a setting compound) and scuff the primer gently with 120 grit.

Comment: Why do you say to not use a setting compound? I'd expect it to work as well there as in other situations.

Comment: Suggested AP because this is supposed to be the last skim, and hot mud is harder to sand (and get that perfect feathered edge).

Answer (score -2):

Polyvinyl acetate dissolves in water and the mud is water based too.  There is a possibility of the mud detaching and falling off.  (Happens all the time) I would recommend sealing in the primer with a waterproof latex with texture.  The texture will help the mud adhere better.

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't the primer dissolve with the application latex paint and discolor it?

Comment: Cured primer does not dissolve in water. Period.

Answer (score -2):

Kilz PVA Drywall Primer is a product to be sold to amateurs that have no clue how drywall should be finished. It is not a cure all. The product can be utilized by spraying it on preexisting drywall to ensure the compound adheres the wallboard. Exp. if one wants to remove a textured ceiling and wants to apply joint compound afterward I would suggest using it to insure the compound adheres to the wallboard instead of "flaking" after the paint prime coat has been applied.

Comment: Reading around the "rant", is seems like your answer is "yes, you can mud directly over the Kilz". Am I reading this correctly? If so, it would be good if you [edit]ed your answer to state that clearly and remove the opinion parts. If you'll take the [tour] and read through the [help] you'll find that this site is different from most in that we're looking for authoritative answers, and "rants" are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Also, this is a 3 year old question, and your answer doesn't really add any additional info to the upvoted answer which says the same thing - "Yes" you can mud over it.